# Read a mp4 and write to anther mp4 creates bigger size

Tags: java, opencv, video

I extracted frames of the mp4 (175KB)file into a folder as jpg files and then trying to write it back to a new mp4 (2.96MB). I see a huge file difference. 
Another point i notice is that the data rate is different in each file ,viz input file 164kbps output file 4149kbps. This probably is causing the issue. Although i could not find the exact API to configure this. any help or suggestion would be very helpful. Shared below code for your reference.

I used the code from openCV samples and tutorials available online.

Read mp4 file: 
            VideoCapture cap = new VideoCapture();

```
    String input = new File(folderPath, "input.mp4").getAbsolutePath();


    cap.open(input);

    int video_length = (int) cap.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
    int frames_per_second = (int) cap.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FPS);
    int frame_number = (int) cap.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES);

    Mat frame = new Mat();

    if (cap.isOpened()) {
        System.out.println("Video is opened");
        System.out.println("Number of Frames: " + video_length);
        System.out.println(frames_per_second + " Frames per Second");
        System.out.println("Converting Video...");

        cap.read(frame);

        while (frame_number <= video_length) {
            Imgcodecs.imwrite(output + "/" + frame_number + ".jpg", frame);
            frame_number++;
        }
        cap.release();

        System.out.println(video_length + " Frames extracted");

    }

    else {
        System.out.println("Fail");
    }
```

Write to mp4

```
final String videoFileName = new File(folderPath,"output.mp4").getAbsolutePath();
    System.out.println("videoFileName: " + videoFileName);
    int FOURCC_MJPG = VideoWriter.fourcc('M', 'P', '4', '2');
    File folder = new File(folderPath);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(new FileFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            String path = pathname.getAbsolutePath();
            String extension = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("."), path.length());
            return extension.contains("jpg");
        }
    });

    VideoWriter writer = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        Mat frame = org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread(listOfFiles[i].getAbsolutePath());


        if (writer == null) {
            writer = new VideoWriter(videoFileName, FOURCC_MJPG, fps, new Size(frame.width(), frame.height()), true);
            if(!writer.isOpened()){
                System.out.println("VideoCap.writeFromCameraToFolder() Bummer!!!!!");
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Captured Frame Width " + frame.width() + " Height " + frame.height());
        writer.write(frame);
        // currentFrame = frame;
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(66);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        frame.release();
    }
    writer.release();
```

Comment: the encoder will have different settings. Since in openCV, you can't change a lot of settings, you might need different libraries like ffmpeg, to read all settings of the original video file and use the same for writing. In the end, size and video quality still might differ, because encoding -> decoding -> encoding will introduce changes for encoders with lossy compression, which nearly every used video encoder has.

Comment: thanks @Micka for the response. do you have any particular wrapper on ffmpeg in mind?

Comment: libAV is the C++ library that is used by ffmpeg

Comment: ah sorry, didnt see that you are using java

Comment: python, C++ too will do the job

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use a third party library, and you're on a supported platform (linux or windows 64 bit), you can have much finer grained control over the FFmpeg encoder using: [Pilecv4j](https://github.com/KognitionAI/pilecv4j)

Here is an exmaple of a JUnit 4 test that I just wrote to do what you're requesting:

```
@Rule public TemporaryFolder tempDir = new TemporaryFolder();

private static long spitVideoIntoFiles(final File inputFile, final File destDir) {
    final AtomicLong frameNum = new AtomicLong(0);

    try(final StreamContext sctx = Ffmpeg2.createStreamContext()
        .createMediaDataSource(inputFile.getAbsolutePath())
        .openChain("default")

        .createFirstVideoStreamSelector()
        .createVideoFrameProcessor(f -> {
            final String filename = new File(destDir, "image-" + frameNum.getAndIncrement() + ".jpg").getAbsolutePath();
            try(CvMat toWrite = f.bgr(false);) {
                uncheck(() -> ImageFile.writeImageFile(toWrite, filename));
            }

            assertTrue(new File(filename).exists());
        })

        .streamContext()

    ;) {
        sctx.play();
    }
    return frameNum.get();
}

private static void encodeFiles(final File imageDir, final long numFrames, final File outputVideo) throws IOException {
    try(CvMat firstFrame = ImageFile.readMatFromFile(new File(imageDir, "image-0.jpg").getAbsolutePath());

        EncodingContext ectx = Ffmpeg2.createEncoder()
            .outputStream(outputVideo.getAbsolutePath())
            .openVideoEncoder("libx264", "vidEncoder")
            .addCodecOptions("preset", "slow")
            .addCodecOptions("crf", "40")

            .enable(firstFrame, false)

    ;) {

        final VideoEncoder ve = ectx.getVideoEncoder("vidEncoder");
        ectx.ready();

        LongStream.range(0, numFrames)
            .mapToObj(fn -> new File(imageDir, "image-" + fn + ".jpg").getAbsolutePath())
            .forEach(frameFile -> {
                try(CvMat mat = uncheck(() -> ImageFile.readMatFromFile(frameFile));) {
                    ve.encode(mat, false);
                }
            });
    }

}

@Test
public void testSplitFrames() throws Exception {

    final File workingFolder = tempDir.newFolder();

    final long numFrames = spitVideoIntoFiles(STREAM_FILE, workingFolder);
    final File destination = tempDir.newFile("out.mp4");
    encodeFiles(workingFolder, numFrames, destination);

    assertTrue(destination.exists());
    System.out.println("Input file size:" + STREAM_FILE.length());
    System.out.println("Output file size:" + destination.length());
}
```

The final output is:

```
Input file size :9355540
Output file size:3558621
```

The documentation for Pilecv4j is still a little raw, but I'm working on it. If you want to use it, and adding something would work for you, let me know.