# Is there a way to take a bunch of images and turn them into an mp4 file in java?

Tags: java, image, video

I am currentrly working on a Way to visualize Fractals in Java. The mathematics behind it work perfectly fine and I am very happy with how the Pics turn out. Now i want to take these Images and turn them into a Video. I've written a Java Program that produces any number of Pictures and saves them (alphabetically) in a new directory. Now I need a way for Java to convert these Images into a Video.
I know there are solutions such as ffmpeg, however I need this process to be repeatable, so I don't think a Command Line Application would be the best Option.

Is there any Way to implement such a function into Java directly ?

Comment: ImageIO can write an animated GIF, but that may not look good if your images have a lot of colors.  For an mp4, I’m pretty sure you’ll need ffmpeg.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use a third party library and the platform is supported (Windows or Linux, 64bit). You can use [Pilecv4j](https://github.com/KognitionAI/pilecv4j) (Full disclosure, I'm the main committer).

There's a test checked in that does exactly this. You can find it here: [TestSplitIntoFiles.java](https://github.com/KognitionAI/pilecv4j/blob/master/lib-ffmpeg/src/test/java/ai/kognition/pilecv4j/ffmpeg/TestSplitIntoFiles.java)

Here is the pertinent function that does this with the minor difference that it's not reading the image file names from the contents on the disk:

```
private static void encodeFiles(final File imageDir, final long numFrames, final File outputVideo) throws IOException {
    try(final CvMat firstFrame = ImageFile.readMatFromFile(new File(imageDir, "image-0.jpg").getAbsolutePath());

        final EncodingContext ectx = Ffmpeg2.createEncoder()
            .outputStream(outputVideo.getAbsolutePath())
            .openVideoEncoder("libx264", "vidEncoder")
            .addCodecOptions("preset", "slow")
            .addCodecOptions("crf", "40")

            .enable(firstFrame, false)

    ;) {

        final VideoEncoder ve = ectx.getVideoEncoder("vidEncoder");
        ectx.ready();

        LongStream.range(0, numFrames)
            .mapToObj(fn -> new File(imageDir, "image-" + fn + ".jpg").getAbsolutePath())
            .forEach(frameFile -> {
                try(CvMat mat = uncheck(() -> ImageFile.readMatFromFile(frameFile));) {
                    ve.encode(mat, false);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

If you decide to give it a try, let me know if you run into any issues. You can use the Issues on GitHub. I've been using it professionally for a while.

Also, see the answer to this question: [Read a mp4 and write to anther mp4 creates bigger size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57320587/read-a-mp4-and-write-to-anther-mp4-creates-bigger-size/73128415#73128415)